# Magento/ExpressionEngine Integration - getting special characters

Tags: integration, magento

I have started integrating an EE cms into Magento using the following tutorial: http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/tutorial-integrating-3rd-party-cms-content-within-magento

It looks like there's EE content populating in Magento, however, it's outputting a ton of special characters. I attached a screenshot of the content area. Any idea what the issue is?[image]

Comment: What are you getting when you try to query EE from Core Mage code?

Comment: I actually ended up setting up a fresh install of both Magento and EE and updated databases, themes and templates and got it working. Still have no clue what the issue was! But in regards to your question, not quite sure what you mean. Please feel free to clarify.